# About the batchUpdate method in JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I got a requirement where I have to read data from a file or database and then update back the records into the database. The volume of data can be millions of records. I am thinking of reusing some existing codes where it makes use of `batchUpdate` method in Spring `JdbcTemplate`. But I got a few questions:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.BatchPreparedStatementSetter-

```
public int[] batchUpdate(String sql,
                         BatchPreparedStatementSetter pss)
                  throws DataAccessException
```

1. Is it by using the `batchUpdate` method, it will reduce the number of database call into just one ? And thus it can save the round trips time of database I/O call. But if it is just one database call, wouldn't the SQL statement that is executed be very long which will exceed the SQL length limitation ? I don't know quite understand how it can reduce the database call into just one.
2. If in the middle of the batch update operation, say there are 1000 records which have already been updated, then there is one record which cannot be updated and throw an exception, is that the previously updated 1000 records will be rolled back as well ? i.e. either all of the records will be updated, or none will be updated ?
3. Given that large volume of records (up to millions), is it a good idea to use this method to do the update ?

Comment: 1. Don't update 1 million rows in one go, the SQL will error, 2. it is one call, all or nothing. 3. No it isn't use something like Spring Batch which has specialized support for things like this.

Comment: 1. I don't believe you'd need to worry about any length limitations. Batch update is a driver optimization - it's not actually constructing one long SQL statement, rather using whatever optimizations it can to not have to constantly get a new connection, verify it, etc.